# What is the difference between "Does everybody..." and "Do everybody..."?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Which one of these is correct?

> - **Do** everyone in the show speak Spanish?
> - **Does** everyone in the show speak Spanish?

And can someone explain when it is appropriate to use the words "do" and "does"?

Answer (score 9):

Singular: use ***does***.
Plural: use ***do***.

> Does that genius (singular) over there speak Spanish?
>
> Do those geniuses (plural) over there speak Spanish?

However odd this may sound, *everyone* is singular. Thus:

> Does everyone in the show speak Spanish?

It's the same as saying:

> Does every single ***one*** (singular) of them in the show speak Spanish?

However (pay attention: this is crucial!), if you change it around a little bit (to plural), you'll have to use *do*:

> Do ***all*** (plural) of those people in the show speak Spanish?