# Everyone with plural usage

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> Everyone want their homes to be in the centres of cities

Is this correct usage or is there any alternative way to convey the same?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "Does everybody..." and "Do everybody..."?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/77609/what-is-the-difference-between-does-everybody-and-do-everybody)

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Please be sure to read "[Details, please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/6700)" to help us write an answer that is most useful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, "everyone" is singular: "Everyone want**s** ..."

You can't *always* count on English words making sense, but in this case, it turns out that "everyone" *can* be broken down into logical components, "every" "one" = "each" "one" --> singular.

The rest of the sentence is a little more complicated.

*Traditionally* it was taught that using a plural pronoun for a singular individual was incorrect. Therefore, both

> "Everyone **want** their ..."

and

> "Everyone **wants** their ..."

would have been considered wrong, and the traditional English-teacher-approved construction would be:

> "Everyone **wants his** ..."

even if the gender of "everyone" is unknown or mixed.

But the people here, on this site, accept the plural pronoun "their" as a gender-neutral option for use as a *singular* pronoun (since, as many people like to point out, it has been used that way "for hundreds of years").

However, this does not mean that [everyone's] "home" needs to become plural. I guess this is subject to debate, but I feel that each person really only has one home:

> "Everyone has *his* one true home."
>
> "Everyone has *her* one true home." (if we are talking about females)
>
> "Everyone has *their* one true home." (acceptable here, now, but not
>   to Mrs. Elliot in her 9th grade English class if I remember right)

So your sentence ought to have a singular verb, a singular pronoun (even if it is the gender-neutral plural-singular option: "their"), and a singular direct object (in this case, since the word is "home"):

> Everyone wants their home to be in the city centre.
>
> Everyone wants their home to be in a city centre.
>
> Everyone wants their home to be in the centre of the city.
>
> Everyone wants their home to be in the centre of a city.

would all work.

Traditionalists would specify a traditional (masculine if the gender is unknown or mixed) singular pronoun:

> Everyone wants his home to be in the city centre.

etc. as above.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite right.

First of all "want" needs to be *wants*.

> Everyone wants their homes to be in the centres of cities.

Because you are using the *plural* of "homes", it is okay to use the plural of "centres" and "cities". This does sound a little like everyone has more than one home, though.

You could instead used the *singular* of "home", in which case "centres" and "cities" need to be singular too:

> Everyone wants their home to be in the centre of a city.

If you were speaking more generally about people's preferences you could also remove "their" and say:

> Everyone wants homes in the centres of cities.

Answer (score 0):

I think the sentence should just be changed as:

> > **Everyone wants their homes to be in the centres of cities**

**Everyone** it self is singular though it takes a plural pronoun **they**.Everyone usually takes a singular verb.So the verb should be *wants* but not *want*
.The verb does not depend on the subject that follows.It does not matter whether it is home or homes but  since the pronoun is **their** homes, cities and centres can be in the plural.